# Google Oauth2 not returning Refresh token upon authentcation

Tags: google-api, angular, google-oauth

I used to develop an authentication module to my Web application which is developed with `Angular2` using the `Oauth2 Google+ API`, the problem here is the google server response does not contain any refresh token besides to the `access_token` , `expires_in` , `token_type` , `id_token` keys ,I tried to revoke the access granted to my application and try again but still the same problem ; here are the parameters added in the `POST` query :

```
    code=4/BXlTY3dLzpUMfu4WuapGjn1du6TCVXEt6Wxjf7-EK_E
    &client_id=429410750270503bndl.apps.googleusercontent.com
    &client_secret=*****GZe11WEgy9Glg2T
    &grant_type=authorization_code
    &redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/loginplus
    &access_type=offline
```

The problem is that in the official docs Google said that it should return a `refresh_token` but I'm not seeing it, I have only those mentioned above, here is the response

```
{
access_token: "ya29..tgLONwAAje6nNWmqV7bMJ_xBQQVS5ZUpXK7m5rCiJwIeeQZTw70fYjOGoX3Z9ZBMvA",
token_type: "Bearer",
expires_in: 3597,
id_token: "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjA3YjlhZDg5ZWFhMTQxNW…bMdi_TtH998qaSdpL05EYG3_1bRijX6AFQwhUoe9ILJeOZM5w"
}
```

I searched a lot but none of the answers helped me, any help ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr
approval_prompt=force is needed in this case to get you a refresh token.

Details:

access_type=offline is always needed in the request if one wants to get a refresh token. (the other answer by PierreDuc is incorrect)
But sometimes you may not get a refresh token after exchanging the "authorization code" that you got. 
Why? 
In order to return a new refresh token We want a user to give consent. If the user has already granted offline consent to your app, we know the app already has a refresh token (at least one) and in general should not be asking for it again and again. So we don't show the approval page and return a code that only gives access token.

If somehow the earlier refresh token was lost and you want to get it again then adding approval_prompt=force in the request will show the user an approval page and will also give you a code that will give the refresh token.

Comment: This has been updated the necessary query param is now prompt=consent

see https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#redirecting

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using `access_type=offline` is that most likely your application has already exchanged an authorization code with an user. If this is the case, it sent back a `response_code` in the first call. You should had stored this code for further usage.

If you want to get a new `refresh_token` you have to ask the user again for consent using your application.

For further reference read [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline)

And in particular this important part:

> Important: When your application receives a refresh token, it is important to store that refresh token for future use. If your application loses the refresh token, it will have to re-prompt the user for consent before obtaining another refresh token. If you need to re-prompt the user for consent, include the prompt parameter in the authorization code request, and set the value to consent.

Comment: It does not work :/ , I thought that was happened because of the granted access so i revoked it but none was changed..

Comment: BTW : I think that the `access_type=offline` should be there in the in the `POST` because of this : https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#refresh-tokens

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Please consider editing it as it'll confuse others. access_type=offline is required if you want to get a refresh token.

Comment: @nvnagr you are right, i've updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

This has been updated the necessary query param is now `prompt=consent`

see https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#redirecting